# Drools :- multiple(thousands) .drl files , each having multiple rules , execution of each file should be controlled as required

Tags: java, drools

I'm new to drools rule engine. In my project, I have multiple `.drl` files of drools to run. But `readknowledgebase()` takes time to run rules. So, I want to learn the best way of loading all rule files (multiple `.drl` files) once, and then run the rules of each `.drl` file one after another as required, instead of running all rules of all `.drl` files each time I make a call to `knowledgebase()`.

Comment: I would suggest you to read the documentation first to get a better understanding about the differences between a .drl file, a Knowledge Base (KieBase) and a Knowledge Session (KieSession).

Answer (score 0):

multiple way we approach this problm
1.use whole,part concept
2. use onDemand concept
3.use Kie stateless session + runtime drools table loading